# Is there a more politically correct/respectful word for maniac/unhinged I can use on a university application?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I want to say something about how "Drama was an outlet for my unhinged energy" but I dont like the word unhinged because its not exactly the most respectful?

Some other words that describe the energy that i want are "unhinged, maniac, crackhead" but none of those would fit very well and are rather insensitive.

I'm trying to write a university application about about how performing arts has given me an outlet for my very high energy personality and a place where I can direct my high enthusiasm. I want to convey that I have all this pent up energy often and drama allowed me to direct it in a healthy and meaningful way.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A few words you could use to describe your vast energy reserves:

Unbridled

Boundless

Inexhaustible

Bottomless

Indefatigable

Any of these convey the notion that you had a ton of energy to direct at some pursuit. Unbridled in particular fits well here, as it also connotes that your energy wasn't otherwise focused or used in a productive way.

Answer (score 3):

In that context, you might want to go with *irrepressible* (or *unbridled* as suggested by Nuclear Wang).

> **Irrepressible (adj):** full of energy and enthusiasm; impossible to stop.
>
> Example: Even the rain failed to dampen his irrepressible spirits. [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irrepressible)

You could also replace 'unhinged energy' with *hyperactivity* or *tireless enthusiasm*.

Answer (score 2):

"Maniac" is not quite it, but *manic* fits well. Although "manic" has a psychiatry-specific connotation, it also has an informal role to roughly mean *driven.*

[Oxford Online]
**Manic**:
frenetically busy; frantic.
"the pace is utterly manic"
Similar:
frenzied
feverish
frenetic

*Drama was the ideal outlet for my manic energy and whacky humor.*

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word *uncontainable* doesn't connote 'out of control' too much nowadays.

> **uncontainable** [adjective]:
>
> (especially of an emotion) very strong.
>
> - *his uncontainable enthusiasm*

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/uncontainable)]